# How to subtract the received anomalies from the dataset

Tags: dataset, subscript

We have a dataset

```
data = ResourceData["Sample Data: Boston Homes"]
```

Find anomalous examples in the dataset.

```
anomalies = FindAnomalies[data]
```

Now I want to remove the lines received in anomalies from the dataset. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to select only these entries that are non in anomalies:

```
data[Select[! MemberQ[anomalies, #] &]]
```

Maybe this helps - if I understood you right

Answer (score 1):

You may also have missed the built-in function `DeleteAnomalies`, which will work directly on the dataset like:

```
DeleteAnomalies[data]
```

You can also pass it an `AnomalyDetectionFunction` which you get from `AnomalyDetection`:

```
ad = AnomalyDetection[data]

DeleteAnomalies[ad, data]
```

Comment: Good to know, your second proposal is new to me (I have not used `AnomalyDetection` so far - I mostly do this separately).

Comment: For second proposal I received: 
DeleteAnomalies::nonopt: Options expected (instead of AnomalyDetectorFunction[Input type: Mixed (number: 7)
False positive rate: 0.001

]) beyond position 1 in DeleteAnomalies[Dataset [<<100>>],AnomalyDetectorFunction[Input type: Mixed (number: 7)
False positive rate: 0.001

]]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules.

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault, I mixed up the order of arguments! I fixed it.